# How to reset all Yosemite's settings and preferences to default?

Tags: macos, settings, defaults

I used this script to modify settings on my mac. [See full script here](https://gist.github.com/MatthewMueller/e22d9840f9ea2fee4716)

```
defaults write com.apple.systemuiserver menuExtras -array \
  "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Bluetooth.menu" \
  "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/AirPort.menu" \
  "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Battery.menu" \
  "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Clock.menu"

sudo chmod 600 /System/Library/CoreServices/Search.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Search

echo ""
echo "Disabling OS X Gate Keeper"
echo "(You'll be able to install any app you want from here on, not just Mac App Store apps)"
sudo spctl --master-disable
sudo defaults write /var/db/SystemPolicy-prefs.plist enabled -string no
defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSQuarantine -bool false

echo ""
echo "Increasing the window resize speed for Cocoa applications"
defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSWindowResizeTime -float 0.001
```

and facing some problem after that. I want to undo all changes to default state.

What is the better way to do.

Comment: What broke when you ran the script?

Comment: You can reset the PRAM http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14222?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US